# How do I reset sorting for a GridView?

Tags: c#, sorting, gridview, webforms

I have a GridView connected to an ObjectDataSource which does the sorting/paging in codebehind. Currently if I choose to sort after some column, change search parameters and then click the Search button, the GridView is still sorted after the column i selected before. In the code behind of the Search button I get the data for the GridView and then databind it.

What I need is a way to reset sorting in the OnClick method of the Search button, so that every time I click on Search the GridView just gets the items without doing sorting on any column.

Thanks for replies!

Comment: can you show your markup and sorting logic?

Comment: Need to see your coding.........

Comment: @Davide Piras: I can't since it is part from a work project. But it shouldn't be necessary for the answer. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1146457.aspx/1) is described how to reset sorting.

```
gridViewInstance.Sort("", SortDirection.Ascending);
```

maybe you will need to rebind the data.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I just placed it immediately before databinding the GridView in the Search button's OnClick method.